# Cannot load admin-ajax.php. No access-control allow origin*

Tags: ajax, headers

I cannot load `admin-ajax.php` and I keep getting this error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ..../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.,. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on...

On local WAMP it worked just to add this:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

(Even if this seems very stupid because next time WordPress updates I guess this would disappear.)

When I upload this to my production server it's still the same message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ..../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.,. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on...

I've tried to modify the `.htaccess` file and that seemed to activate CORS, but that won't affect `admin-ajax.php`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>
```

I've also tried to install [WP-CORS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cors/) plugin without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are filters for `allowed_http_origins` and `add_allowed_origins`.
You can use them to set the proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response to your AJAX call.

Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('allowed_http_origins', 'add_allowed_origins');

function add_allowed_origins($origins) {
    $origins[] = 'https://www.yourdomain.com';
    return $origins;
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me. I still get the same error.

Comment: i have used all method but still i can't resolve my same issue. If you have another method please share. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```